# Galaxy Tablet browser sniff / detection

Tags: javascript, android, tablet, galaxy

Is there an effective way to sniff the browser type for the Samsung Galaxy Tablet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the default browser, the user agent will have the device model number in it (SGH-T849). Curiously, on the Tab, I don't see a way to change the user agent. That being said, people do use alternative browsers, which may or may not include the device model number in the user agent.

Comment: the user agent will have the device model number in it (SGH-T849) nooooo, while this is true in as far as it goes, a single brand of phone might bear a variety of model numbers according to which revision it is. This is really unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is the fact that we can’t detect the Galaxy Tablet that lands you on the mobile versions of websites in the first place. Because there’s no practical way to distinguish a Galaxy Tablet from a phone.